# Validating input with Joi - Express and using it in React

Tags: reactjs, express, joi

I'm trying to validate a form using Redux Form, Thunk and then Joi on the backend. 
What I'd like to do is when the user submits the form, I'd like to dispatch my action, which calls my API, and then if the Joi middleware catches a problem with the form, react on the frontend accordingly based on what the error is.

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to access the json that follows on from the error status code sent back by Joi.

Here's my dispatch action on the frontend:

```
export const signUp = (
  newUser: User
): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:2000/users/signup", newUser);
  } catch (error) {
     console.log("THE ERROR", error)
  }
};
```

And then on the backend, this is my joi middleware:

```
validateBody: (schema) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
            if (result.error)  {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "this is your error" })
            }

            // validated values are in req.value.body if it's there
            if (!req.value) {
                req.value = {};
            }
            req.value['body'] = result.value;
            // the next allows the middleware to pass through
            next();
        }

    },
```

If I run this with a problem in the form, I get

```
THE ERROR Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

But I can't find how to access the json ("this is your error") in the catch block. Any help would be really appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios error is inside error.response.

You can access the error like this:

```
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:2000/users/signup", newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      /*The request was made and the server responded with a
        status code that falls out of the range of 2xx  */
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      /* The request was made but no response was received, `error.request`
       * is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance
       * of http.ClientRequest in Node.js */
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request and triggered an Error
      console.log("Error", error.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks! As a further question, do you know why I can't return res to the event handler if everything works? I'm able to console log the error in the handler, but not the res when the try block works...

Comment: @Raph117 I couldn't understand what you meant, but answering another question in the comments very difficult, maybe you can ask a new question.

Comment: @Raph117  it would be better to ask a new question,  it is not very time consuming, and if the answer was helpful please consider accepting it.

Comment: I will definitely look at your new question, and try to help if I can.

Comment: @Raph117 I was about to answer your new question, why did you deleted?
You need to return data like this: return response.data. Also please don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: Hi - it was because I was making a basic mistake. I wasn't returning a status code from the server. Thanks for your help! I'm now having trouble with Typescript and redux-thunk...